# django: unable to login using django Remote authentication

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm developing a new django project ,in the i have created a simple login page, which i want to just login and go to the home page.

when i try to login i'm getting and login is not happening successfully.

Project name: mysite
appname : dsmdata

Below are the codings

1. project(mysite) Settings.py file below

```js
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

os.environ['REMOTE_USER'] = "dsmuser1"

#LOGIN_URL = '/dsm/login'

# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dsm/logged_in'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y%cwxi-m5s-0zct+k%$u1$z!#o#u52zu_!z*#8(8saqdx+6t$l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'dsmdata.pmauth.pmauth',
]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
     },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'C:/karthik/Projects/Postgres-DB-All/Statistics/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

1. Login page html:

   ---

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}

<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}

<p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <!-- <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3> -->
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </p>
                        <p class="bs-component">
                            <center>
                                <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="login" />
                            </center>
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}


<script>
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
$("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").css("display","none");
{% endif %}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

2. forms.py (from my app , appname -dsmdata)

```js
   #log/forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django import forms

# If you don't do this you cannot use Bootstrap CSS
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))
```

3. My custom authentication class derived from RemoterUserBackend class

```js
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class pmauth(RemoteUserBackend):
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None):
        logger.debug("Inside authenticate") 
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Create a new user. There's no need to set a password
            # because only the password from settings.py is checked.
            user = User(username=username)
            user.is_staff = True
            user.is_superuser = True
            user.is_authenticated = True
#           user.is_anonymous = abc.test
            user.save()
        return user        
    
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
    
    def configure_user(self,user):
        """Set user groups and privs. 
        This method is called the first time a non-django user logs in.
        A user is created in the django database, this method
        adds the new user to the appropriate groups, and 
        sets privs. """

        #Add all remote users to a group
        #user.groups.add(s.ALL_USERS_GROUP)

        #all remote users are staff - so they can access the admin interface
        user.is_staff=True
        
        user.is_superuser=True
        
        user.is_authenticated = True
        
        user.is_anonymous = abc.test
        
        logger.debug("Inside configure_user") 
        logger.debug(user.username)  


        #To determine if the user is to have further priviledges
        #we consult LDAP

        #connect to ldap server
#         l = ldap.initialize(s.LDAP_SERVER)

        #get list of superusers
#         superusers=l.search_s(s.LDAP_SEARCH_TREE,\
#                 ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,\
#                 s.LDAP_FILTER)\
#                 [0][1][s.LDAP_FIELD]

        #close LDAP Connection
#         l.unbind()

        #Check if this user should be a superuser. 
#         if user.username in superusers:
#             user.is_superuser=True
        #dsm.authenticate = true
        user.save()
        print("successfully saved the user")
        return user
```

5. project(mysite)  urls.py

```js
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from dsmdata.forms import LoginForm
from dsmdata.pmauth import pmauth


urlpatterns = [
    #path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('polls/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'', include('dsmdata.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view() , {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name="login" ),
    #url(r'^login/$', pmauth , {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name="login" ),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': '/login'}),        
    #re_path(r'^dsm/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    #re_path(r'^dsm/login', include('dsm.urls')),    
]
```

6. dsmdata application views.py

```js
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



from pip._vendor.requests.api import request

# Create your views here.
# this login required decorator is to not allow to any  
# view without authenticating

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):     
    
    
    return render(request,"home.html", testdict)
   



# Create your views here.
```

Comment: What do you mean "login is not happening"? What happens instead? Do you get any errors? Does it redirect to home without logging the user in?

Comment: Yes i got the below error,

Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.

Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed, please login with an account that has access.

Comment: Its not going to home. It stays in the login page itself.

Comment: any help on this